# IntelliJ services window does not show that a running task is running

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

From time to time certain tasks/services in WebStorm stop showing their true state(running/not running) and appeared to be no running from the services toolbar.

Here you can see that the `firebase-emulator` task is appeared to not running when it actually do running:

[image]

I can confirm that by interacting with the emulator and by looking at the configurations toolbar to the top right:

[image]

This is most probably a bug in WebStorm because it has not fixed yet for at least 2 years. Changing the task name to other name fixes it until it happens again, which is something very annoying to do. This is not clear why it is happening.

I'm running on the latest WebStorm 2023.2.1.

Anyone was able to solve it?

Comment: It is worth submitting an issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/ with steps to reproduce it, and logs (Help > Collect logs...).